# Visual Code extension/autocomplete/snippets stopped working

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm running the latest version of visual code on a mac. I am having issues where 'everything' suddenly stops working. All the extensions no longer work, autocomplete fails and my snippets don't show up. If I close the folder / quit vs code and reopen everything works fine .. until the next time.
I tried disabling all the recent extension but to no avail, apart from that I'm not sure what to do.
Any help / ideas would be appreciated on how to resolve this. Thanks

Running the developer tools it get this error (50 times)

```
[Extension Host] Error: Unknown decoration type key: TextEditorDecorationType159
    at t.resolveDecorationOptions (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28:1457609)
    at t._resolveDecorationOptions (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28:1619470)
    at t.setDecorations (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28:1263889)
    at e.setDecorations (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28:3128351)
    at t.$trySetDecorations (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28:3140749)
    at t.e.handle (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28:3100447)
    at s (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28:1029376)
    at f (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:28:1030031)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Try running the `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools command` from the command palette. Do you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @MattBierner - thanks Matt had to wait for it to screw up again - I did as you suggested and updated my question with the output - actually have traced it back to one of the extensions! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing this but someone else on VS Code team may have some ideas. Can you please file a new issue with the information from this question: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new Thanks!